# Image slider smooth animation effect on-click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple slider with navigation div's from the right. Each div is a smaller image of a slider, when i click on this div it should move to particular slide.

How can i animate it in order that on-click it slides smoothly?

```
  $('.nav-img-1').click(function(){
    currentSlide = 1;
    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
  });
  $('.nav-img-2').click(function(){
    currentSlide = 2;
    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', -500);
  });
  $('.nav-img-3').click(function(){
    currentSlide = 3;
    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', -1000);
  });
```

Example you can find [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gorez16rus/r57mdwyh/)

Comment: Why you dont use animate as well as used in startSlider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `animate()` the same way you are using it in the continuous sliding:

```
$('.nav-img-1').click(function(){
    currentSlide = 1;
    $slideContainer.stop().animate({'margin-left': 0}, 1000);
});
$('.nav-img-2').click(function(){
    currentSlide = 2;
    $slideContainer.stop().animate({'margin-left': -500}, 1000);
});
$('.nav-img-3').click(function(){
    currentSlide = 3;
    $slideContainer.stop().animate({'margin-left': -1000}, 1000);
});
```

Realize that there is also `stop()` before `animate()` to stop the other animations going on with the `.slide`. I recommend putting that onto any other animation you currently have or will have for the slider.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mqzhkbdu/